# Why is the RigidBody still moving evan if the code is not called anymore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move an object ( a cat mesh) forward, in the attempt to make an infinite runner. As any infinite runner, I need to move the object forward ( more specific the cat mesh) but if the cat reaches a wall or a fence it will stop moving forward and "jump up", on the fence.

So, to do that I am moving the object with `Getcomponent<rigidBody>().velocity = new vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 2f;`
(I find out that if I move the object manually with `transform.position = Vector3.forward;` the cat object will stop in the trigger that should make the cat move up the fence THAN move to the position on top of the fence, so to avoid the cat from blocking in to the trigger I used  `Getcomponent<rigidBody>().velocity = new vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 2f;` so that the RigidBody can pass freely through the trigger)

The problem is that if I use the `Getcomponent<rigidBody>().velocity = new vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 2f;`  the cat is not stopping, it goes forward and in the same time it goes to the position on top of the fence, I want it to go straight to the fence.

As you can see in the code that I will provide, even if I stop calling
 `Getcomponent<rigidBody>().velocity = new vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 2f;` after the trigger, the cat is STILL moving forward, and I don't know why. Can you point out what I am doing wrong or what I should change?

Also, feel free to point out and tell me ANY problem or poor written code issues that you notice.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CatManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool isRunning = true;
    private bool jumpFence = false;

    //makes the RigidBody of the cat wait a litle until it will move towards the cat destination
    private bool startTimerJump = false;

    //The position at which the cat will jump
    private Vector3 catDestination;

    //The object that the trigger is attached to
    private GameObject targetObject;

    //The Rigid body of the object this script is attached to
    private Rigidbody rb;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        StartCoroutine (JumpOnFence ());
        NormalRunning ();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag ("Fence")) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Collision");
            isRunning = false;
            startTimerJump = true;
            targetObject = col.gameObject;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator JumpOnFence ()
    {
        if (startTimerJump == true) 
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
            isRunning = false;
            jumpFence = true;
            startTimerJump = false;
        }
        if (jumpFence == true) 
        {
            catDestination = new Vector3 (targetObject.transform.parent.position.x, targetObject.transform.parent.position.y + targetObject.transform.parent.localScale.y / 2 + transform.localScale.y / 3, targetObject.transform.parent.position.z);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, catDestination, Time.deltaTime * 3f);
        }

    }
    void NormalRunning()
    {
        if (isRunning == true)
        {
            Debug.Log ("The cat is moving forward");
            rb.velocity = Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 2f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want it to stop set the velocity to 0.

Comment: Ok. It worked. Thank you very much :*